# HttpUrlConnection gets response body on connect()

Tags: java, android, inputstream, httpurlconnection, bufferedinputstream

Consider the following code.

```
try {
    httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(strings[0]).openConnection();

    httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(Config.HTTP_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
    httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(Config.HTTP_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

    httpURLConnection.connect();

    responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
    httpURLConnection.getHeaderFields();
}
finally {
    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
}
```

The issue is even when I don't use the `InputStream` to read the response, in my Internet/Wifi connection logs I can see the response-body. What I want is simply to check a field in the header and based upon that field I will continue reading the `InputStream`.

My questions are these:

1. Is it correct behavior for the connected stream to automatically download all/partial file even before a `BufferedInputStream` is created and read from?
2. If yes, then is it possible to stop the file download until an `InputStream` is used to read the response?
3. If not then is there something I am doing wrong or missing?

Comment: can you describe what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: @VivekMishra Sure I only want to download any response-body when `Last-Modified` time is later than my last downloaded time. Some sites do not support `If-Modified-Since`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The response includes both the header and the body, the server does not stop for the client to acknowledge the headers before sending the body.
   At the time the client is able to read the response code from the headers, a part of the body has already been sent, the size of which depends on the network latency, buffering, ....
   The current implementation of `HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode()` even use `getInputStream()` to ensure that the connection is in the correct state.
2. The client can choose to ignore the body, but it's usually not recommended, because it may prevent a persistent connection to be reused.
   I am not sure about Android but since Java 6, a background thread is automatically used to read the remaining data.
3. If `If-Modified-Since` is not an option, why not use a [`HEAD` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) ? :

> The HTTP HEAD method requests the headers that are returned if the
>   specified resource would be requested with an HTTP GET method. Such a
>   request can be done before deciding to download a large resource to
>   save bandwidth, for example.

Comment: *the server does not stop for the client to acknowledge the headers before sending the body* Is this a common practice or a standard? If it is a standard could you site some resources?

Comment: The Head Request link states "*A response to a HEAD method should not have a body*". Does that mean sending of the body is still determined by the server?

Comment: It is not that `If-Modified-Since` is not an option, but more some servers may or may not support it. And I need to know if at all possible whether the source file has been changed.

Comment: the server does wait because there is nothing in the HTTP protocol for that, at least for the response (as opposed to the 100-continue mecanism for the request)

Comment: a HEAD request indicates quite strongly that you are not interested in the body, if the server still send it, there is nothing you can do

Comment: Hmm. I will wait for a couple of days to see if a better answer comes in, if not then I will accept your answer as correct.